# stringWithContentsOfFile Deprecated

Tags: nsstring

I use the following code in my app, but it gives a warning that `stringWithContentsOfFile` is deprecated.

Can anyone tell me how to avoid this warning? Will this warning affect my app in the future?

```
NSString *myData= [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thought I might expand on daveoncode's answer a bit, so if you are not interested in the errors, you can just simply write

```
NSString *myData= [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

and it will work as you expected.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:` or `stringWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error:`